# indentation problem, return outside function

Tags: python, indentation

Can't understand why there is an error

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
b = []
for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        b.append(i)
        return b
print (b)
```

output

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function                                                                                                      
[Finished in 0.33s with exit code 1]
```

I need a code that takes list "a" and makes a new list that has only the even elements of this list in it

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? `return` is used to return a value from a function and you have no function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Have you not done a Python tutorial? You should do that first; this site isn't built to teach the basics.

Comment: Er, why do you think this is an indentation problem? Does your code have a function you're not showing us? If so, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: What do you think `b` is being returned *to* in this example? Perhaps you simply want to terminate the loop with `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return is a keyword in python that is used to return a value for a function.
They can only be used inside functions. For example:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
i = add(4,5)
```

i would be equal to 9, because add(4,5) would return 4+5, so it would be i = 9

The problem is that you are trying to use the return keyword outside of a function.
Other than that, I don't understand why you are trying to return b.
If you delete the line with return, it will simply add the even numbers in list a to list b, which I think is what you are looking for.

Also you may consider watching some python courses in Youtube. They are very helpful and save you a lot of time which you would spend on trying to solve errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

**If not using a function**

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100] 
b = []
for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        b.append(i)
print (b)
```

**If using a function**

```
def run(a):
    b=[]
    for i in a:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            b.append(i)
    return b

a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
print(run(a))
```

Comment: @Mustafa Aslan Thanks a lot, i just quit learning code by tutorials and videos and trying to write code by myself and now see that have problems with even with basics